# Holding Child Call in Twilio Studio even after Parent Call Ends

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twilio-studio

I'm currently building an IVR flow using Twilio Studio, and I'm facing an issue with handling calls. Here's an overview of the flow:

1.I initiate an outgoing call to the user using the "Make Outgoing Call" widget.

2.After the user answers, I ask some IVR questions.

3.Upon correct answers, I connect the call to my employee using TwiML like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Number
            statusCallbackEvent="answered"
            statusCallback="{{call_back_url}}/yes/{{attempt}}/{{flow_id}}"
            statusCallbackMethod="POST">
            {{doctor_number}}
        </Number>
    </Dial>
    <Redirect>
        https://webhooks.twilio.com/v1/Accounts/xxx/Flows/xx?FlowEvent=return&amp;test=success&amp;child_call_sid={{ChildCallSid}}&amp;child_call_status={{child_call_status}}&amp;child_call_duration={{child_call_duration}}
    </Redirect>
</Response>
```

The problem arises when the user ends the call (parent call); it terminates both the parent and child calls. However, I want to keep the child call active even if the parent call ends so that I can reconnect the user with my agent or employee.

How can I achieve this in Twilio Studio? Is there a way to hold the child call independently of the parent call?

Answer (score 0):

In a Voicecall, if either the caller or the callee disconnect, then all call legs will end.

If you do not want this behavior, then use a [Voice Conference](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/conference). A Voice Conference can be setup to not end if one of the members hangs up. This totorial "[How to build a conference call line with Twilio Studio](https://www.twilio.com/blog/build-conference-call-line-twilio-studio)" will walk you through the setup. Using a "conference" even with only two callers works great and unlocks many features only available within the conference.